# Kotlin Inheritance / Declaration with Generics

Tags: generics, inheritance, kotlin

I'm trying to initiate the `RoomAlarmRepository` inside the RepoInit 1 & 2.

The first one says "Type mismatch", and wouldn't let me compile. That is, unless I cast it like in `RepoInit2`, at which point it tells me that the cast is unchecked.

```
class RepoInit1(app: App) {
internal val repo: AlarmRepository<AlarmModel> = RoomAlarmRepository(app.database)
}

class RepoInit2(app: App) {
internal val repo: AlarmRepository<AlarmModel> = RoomAlarmRepository(app.database) as AlarmRepository<AlarmModel>
}


class RoomAlarmRepository(val database: AppDatabase) : AlarmRepository<RoomAlarmModel> {

}

class RoomAlarmModel : AlarmModel {


}
```

I'm currently using the second one, as it actually works. I know I'm missing something where I declare the variable, but I'm not sure what it is.

[image: Type mismatch]
[image: Unchecked Cast]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the generic type it with the `out` modifier as covariant.
See here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html for details.

```
class RepoInit2(...) {
    internal val repo: AlarmRepository<out AlarmModel> = RoomAlarmRepository(...)
}
```